# MacBook Pro Retina & 3 Dell SP2309W's

Tags: mac, display

So, my main rig is on its way out and I am seriously considering replacing my old Dell w/ a new MacBook Pro.  With that being said, I have 3 gorgeous [Dell SP2309W's](http://accessories.dell.com/sna/products/displays/productdetail.aspx?c=us&l=en&s=gen&sku=320-7641) that I would like to make use of.

Can anyone comment on the capability of using these monitors w/ a new MacBook Pro Ret?  As I understand it, the thunderbolt port can act as a mini-DVI.  With the right conversations, can I run 2 DVI & 1 HDMI from the MBP to get 3 monitors running?  Would I regret such a decision?

I am not 100% sure this is the way I would like to go, but I want to investigate my options.  Any thoughts / feedback would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several converter dongles that will turn a Thunderbolt port into either an HDMI, DVI or VGA connector depending on what you like - I believe your displays support all of these connectors. So that's two of your displays covered. You can hook up the third display to the HDMI port.

From what I've found, there appear to be no specific issues when hooking up three monitors and graphics performance appears to remain decent:

- http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5219#dispnum
- http://www.macrumors.com/2012/06/20/retina-macbook-pro-can-run-three-external-displays-simultaneously/
- http://arstechnica.com/apple/2012/06/new-macbooks-can-manage-many-many-monitors/
- http://news.cnet.com/8301-33620_3-57457948-278/how-the-mac-finally-won-me-away-from-windows/
- http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-3121_7-57460642-220/how-to-power-four-simultaneous-screens-with-the-retina-macbook-pro/

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks so much!  That last link there was EXACTLY what I was looking for!  I really wanted some kind of hands-on information rather than an "in-theory" kind of response.  Great!